# Antlr grammar with single quotes doubling as operators

Tags: antlr

I am working on an Antlr grammar in which single quotes are used both as operators and in string literals, something like:

```
operand:     DIGIT | STRINGLIT | reference;
expression:  operand SQUOTE;
STRINGLIT:   '\''  ~('\\'|'\'')* '\'';
```

Expressions like `1'` parse correctly, but when there is input that matches `~('\\'|'\'')*` after the quote, such as `1'+2`, the lexer attempts to match `STRINGLIT` and fails. I'd like to be able to recover and emit `SQUOTE`. Any ideas how to accomplish it?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you  show us exactly what `reference` looks like?

Answer (score 0):

After testing this grammar a bit in Antlrworks, I think that your problem is that you are being too restrictive here.  Antlr would be able to parse `1'+2` if you had a rule that accepted something after it has seen `operand SQUOTE`.  Since ANTLR doesn't know what to do with the `+2`, it throws an exception.